# Getting access to apolloClient within getInitialProps through SSR

Tags: apollo, next.js, react-apollo, apollo-client

I was hoping to get information to populate through SSR before the page loads. I've been following this example https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo-auth/pages but been noticing the apolloClient doesn't exist within getInitialProps.

My withAuth.js

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

export const withApollo = (PageComponent, { ssr = true } = {}) => {
    const WithApollo = ({ apolloClient, apolloState, ...pageProps }) => {
        const client = apolloClient || initApolloClient(apolloState, { getToken });
        return (
            <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                <PageComponent {...pageProps} />
            </ApolloProvider>
        );
    };

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        // Find correct display name
        const displayName = PageComponent.displayName || PageComponent.name || 'Component';

        // Warn if old way of installing apollo is used
        if (displayName === 'App') {
            console.warn('This withApollo HOC only works with PageComponents.');
        }

        // Set correct display name for devtools
        WithApollo.displayName = `withApollo(${displayName})`;

        // Add some prop types
        WithApollo.propTypes = {
            // Used for getDataFromTree rendering
            apolloClient: PropTypes.object,
            // Used for client/server rendering
            apolloState: PropTypes.object
        };
    }

    if (ssr || PageComponent.getInitialProps) {
        WithApollo.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
            const { AppTree } = ctx;
            console.log(AppTree);

            // Run all GraphQL queries in the component tree
            // and extract the resulting data
            const apolloClient = (ctx.apolloClient = initApolloClient(
                {},
                {
                    getToken: () => getToken(ctx.req)
                }
            ));

            const pageProps = PageComponent.getInitialProps ? await PageComponent.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};

            // Only on the server
            if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
                // When redirecting, the response is finished.
                // No point in continuing to render
                if (ctx.res && ctx.res.finished) {
                    return {};
                }

                if (ssr) {
                    try {
                        // Run all GraphQL queries
                        console.log('trying');
                        const { getDataFromTree } = await import('@apollo/react-ssr');
                        await getDataFromTree(
                            <AppTree
                                pageProps={{
                                    ...pageProps,
                                    apolloClient
                                }}
                            />
                        );
                    } catch (error) {
                        // Prevent Apollo Client GraphQL errors from crashing SSR.
                        // Handle them in components via the data.error prop:
                        // https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data-error
                        console.error('Error while running `getDataFromTree`', error);
                    }
                }

                // getDataFromTree does not call componentWillUnmount
                // head side effect therefore need to be cleared manually
                Head.rewind();
            }

            // Extract query data from the Apollo store
            const apolloState = apolloClient.cache.extract();

            return {
                ...pageProps,
                apolloState
            };
        };
    }

    return WithApollo;
};

let apolloClient = null;

/**
 * Always creates a new apollo client on the server
 * Creates or reuses apollo client in the browser.
 */
const initApolloClient = (...args) => {
    // Make sure to create a new client for every server-side request so that data
    // isn't shared between connections (which would be bad)
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return createApolloClient(...args);
    }

    // Reuse client on the client-side
    if (!apolloClient) {
        apolloClient = createApolloClient(...args);
    }

    return apolloClient;
};

const createApolloClient = (initialState = {}, { getToken }) => {
    let fetchOptions = {};
    const HTTP_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4000/api';

    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
        uri: HTTP_ENDPOINT,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        fetch,
        fetchOptions
    });

    const authLink = setContext((request, { headers }) => {
        const token = getToken();
        return {
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
            }
        };
    });

    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined', // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
        link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
        cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState)
    });
};

const getToken = () => {
    return Cookies.get('token');
};
```

I'm using it as a HOC in my _app.js file and been trying to get access to the apolloClient in my Signin component hoping to do a check if a person is logged in, in order to redirect them (also would like to know in order to make the navbar dynamic)

Thank you for the help on this one

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code and now you should be able to access apolloClient within getInitialProps.

```
const apolloClient = (ctx.ctx.apolloClient = initApolloClient({}, { 
      getToken: () => getToken(ctx.req)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed one thing i.e. to return the `apolloClient` while returning the `PageProps` and `ApolloCache` when SSR is `true`.

```
// Extract query data from the Apollo store
const apolloState = apolloClient.cache.extract();

return {
    ...pageProps,
    apolloState,
    // To get access to client while in SSR
    apolloClient
};
```